# DidselectRowAtIndexPath is working for selected cell in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm creating expandable tableview when we click any cell the respective cell should expand, if we click the same cell it should collapse. Upto this working fine. In each cell i've some UI element which are taken in the custom cell nib. My issue is when i clicked last cell it showing the elements, but when i click the above cells the UI elements are not displaying it showing blank. Here is my what i've tried in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
//    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if ([_expandedCells containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [_expandedCells removeObject:indexPath];
}
else
{
    if ([_expandedCells count])
    {
        [_expandedCells removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [_expandedCells addObject:indexPath];

}
//    [self.voicemailTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray     arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//    [self.voicemailTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.voicemailTable indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];

}



- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

CGFloat kExpandedCellHeight = 150.0f;
CGFloat kNormalCellHeigh = 60.0f;


if ([_expandedCells containsObject:indexPath])
{

    customCell.playBtn.hidden = NO;
    customCell.minimumLbl.hidden = NO;
    customCell.maximumLbl.hidden = NO;
    customCell.sliderBG.hidden = NO;
    customCell.slider.hidden = NO;

    return kExpandedCellHeight;
}
else
{

    customCell.playBtn.hidden = YES;
    customCell.minimumLbl.hidden = YES;
    customCell.maximumLbl.hidden = YES;
    customCell.sliderBG.hidden = YES;
    customCell.slider.hidden = YES;

    return kNormalCellHeigh;
}

}
```

This what i'm tried for showing after selecting the cell in the table. Here _expandableCells is an NSmutableArray. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set delegate and datasource for tableview ?

Comment: why do you call this line [_expandedCells removeObjectAtIndex:0]; ?

Comment: yeah i seted delegate and datasource for the tableview @iOSNoob

Comment: Here im inserting the indexpath into the _expandedCells array if the cell is selected and removing after deselecting the index value @YuviGr

Comment: but why do you remove the first object in the _expandedCell? it has nothing to do with the currently selected cell

Comment: That helps when the another cell is selected the previous cell will collapse, that means in that array i'm inserting one object each time only and removing that object and inserting the new object into the array

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all the cell configuration code to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Like so:

```
YourCustomCellClass *customCell = [tableView - (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: <your cell identifier> forIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([_expandedCells containsObject:indexPath]){
    customCell.playBtn.hidden = NO;
    customCell.minimumLbl.hidden = NO;
    customCell.maximumLbl.hidden = NO;
    customCell.sliderBG.hidden = NO;
    customCell.slider.hidden = NO;
}else{
    customCell.playBtn.hidden = YES;
    customCell.minimumLbl.hidden = YES;
    customCell.maximumLbl.hidden = YES;
    customCell.sliderBG.hidden = YES;
    customCell.slider.hidden = YES;
}
return customCell;
```

Comment: Oh!! Sorry yar.. i already tried with that. My actual aim is when i selects the cell it should expand and display play button and slider in the expanded cell. if i press the play button one audio file should play. For me the respective audio is working for last cell which show all elements in that.

Comment: The problem is you are configuring a cell in a wrong place. The heightForRowAtIndexPath is not meant for that